# Executing a SQL file in interactive impala-shell session

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

In an interactive impala-shell session, is there a way to load and execute a text file containing one or more SQL statements? In Hive's beeline, for example, you can use `!run <filename>` to run the SQL commands in that file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. You can [file a JIRA](https://issues.cloudera.org).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible - see `impala-shell -h` (version v2.1.1-cdh5):

```
-f QUERY_FILE, --query_file=QUERY_FILE
                    Execute the queries in the query file, delimited by ;
                    [default: none]
```

combine this with `shell` command in interactive mode:

shell impala-shell -f file;

Comment: This runs in a different session.
Not useful if you want to e.g. use the file to set variables in the current session.